# How to merge multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, this is a bit tricky to explain.  We have an audit table that keeps a record of every field that gets changed in a table.  So say we have a table that looks like this:

```
RecordID    Forename    Surname    DOB
1           Bob         Smith      10/01/2000
2           Joe         Bloggs     11/01/2000
3           Mike        Jones      12/01/2000
```

Now, say I deleted these three rows.  The audit table would keep a record of these deletes, and it does so like this:

```
PrimaryKeyValue    FieldName    OldValue    NewValue
<RecordID=1>       Forename     Bob         NULL
<RecordID=1>       Surname      Smith       NULL
<RecordID=1>       DOB          10/01/2000  NULL
<RecordID=2>       Forename     Joe         NULL
<RecordID=2>       Surname      Bloggs      NULL
<RecordID=2>       DOB          11/01/2000  NULL
<RecordID=3>       Forename     Mike        NULL
<RecordID=3>       Surname      Jones       NULL
<RecordID=3>       DOB          12/01/2000  NULL
```

So, my question is, is there any way of putting these records from the audit table back into the first table.  In my case, some records have been deleted that shouldn't have been, and all I have are these audit records.  And there are a lot more of them than in my example here, so to do it all manually will take forever.  I am hoping someone here knows some clever way of doing multiple inserts using the bottom table so they appear in the first table again as shown.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you searched for a solution? Have you tried anything out yet? It's not an uncommon problem. Maybe look for the pivot operator or conditional aggregation?

Comment: The result you want is known as pivot table. A lot of answers already exist here.

Comment: Good stuff, I will search up on pivot, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you might have changes mixed in with a delete on the same record.  Is there anything that ties the `NULL` records all together?